# I need a complete idiots guide to creating the initial cron setup

Tags: cron, cron-job

I have found the guides for setting up the cron in CiviCRM.

I cant understand anything. I am using Wordpress. can someone please give me a complete step to step for setting this up as I really don't understand it and I need it to clear the cache every 5 minutes

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would need to know more about your hosting arrangements to provide any more detailed help.

Setting up cron can be confusing and it is hard to provide a complete step-by-step guide since there are so many variables. If you have read the [docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/) and the cron questions on SE and still don't have a clue where to start then you may be best finding someone [here](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors?country_id=) to help you.  It's usually a quick job for anyone familiar with this stuff.

Also, why do you need to clear the cache (which one?) every 5 minutes?

Comment: @Dan This is unfortunately the state of things, because every web hosting company has its own way of setting up cron.  You may get more help if you say what your hosting situation is - are you using a control panel, like CPanel or Hestia?  If so, which one?  Is this your own server with command-line access?

Comment: I am using instahost which doesnt give command line access only http.
Instahost uses a stackcp.

Also I need to it clear the cache so that my custom fields work on the webforms i have created as per previous posts. they won't show for anonymous users without clearing the cache, so at the moment new members are having to wait for me to clear the cache first.

As i work for a charity fees are limited, especially during the times we have had recently, so im trying to not only do this myself, but also learn how to in the process

Comment: Ok, if you want to do it yourself step through the doc link I posted earlier and ask specific questions when you get stuck.  You shouldn't need to be clearing caches like that - I'd suggest adding a link to your previous question about that.